# Is there an easy way to export 1 module and 1 form from 1 Excel file to dozens of other Excel files?

Tags: vba, excel

The title pretty much says it all.  I'm trying to find a way to export 1 Module (named Module1) and one Form (named UserForm1).  I know the object names are very creative.  Is there a way to export these 2 objects from one Excel template, to dozens of other Excel templates that have no code, but need the same code I have in this one file?

I looked at the link below and followed the instructions.

http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win002.htm

With the 2 noted references added in, I start to step through the code, and get to this line:

```
For Each cmpComponent In wkbSource.VBProject.VBComponents
```

Here I get an error that says 'Run-time error 1004 Method VBProject of object Workbook failed'.

One more thing, I commented out a few lines around:

```
'If wkbSource.VBProject.Protection = 1 Then'
```

I don't really care about that part.  Any idea how I can make this work?

TIA.

Comment: You need to grant programmatic access to the VBIDE API (from macro security settings), and then reference the VBIDE API (VBA Extensibility object model, *tools > references*) - get the `VBComponent` you want to export, export it. Then get the `VBProject` object for the file(s) you want to import it to, import it. If you have a *specific* question on your way, we're here to help. But *this* question, as is, is *too broad*.

Comment: Ok, I just modified my OP.  I hope that adds some more dimension to what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works!!

```
Option Explicit

Sub UpdateVBComponents()

    Dim VBP As Object
    Dim wkbSource As Workbook
    Dim wkbOpen As Workbook
    Dim strSourceFolder As String
    Dim strTempModule As String
    Dim strTempUserForm As String
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim lngCnt As Long

    Set wkbSource = ThisWorkbook 'or ActiveWorkbook

    On Error Resume Next
    Set VBP = wkbSource.VBProject
    If VBP Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "You'll need to allow access to the VBA project object model.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    If VBP.Protection = 1 Then
        MsgBox "Unable to continue because the VBA project is protected.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If

    strSourceFolder = "C:\Users\Domenic\Desktop\"
    If Len(Dir(strSourceFolder, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Unable to continue becuase no such folder exists.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    Else
        If Right(strSourceFolder, 1) <> "\" Then
            strSourceFolder = strSourceFolder & "\"
        End If
    End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    strTempModule = Environ("temp") & "\temp_module1.bas"
    strTempUserForm = Environ("temp") & "\temp_userform1.bas"

    With VBP
        .VBComponents("Module1").Export strTempModule
        .VBComponents("UserForm1").Export strTempUserForm
    End With

    strFile = Dir(strSourceFolder & "*.xlsm", vbNormal)

    lngCnt = 0
    Do While Len(strFile) > 0
        Set wkbOpen = Workbooks.Open(strSourceFolder & strFile)
        With wkbOpen
            With .VBProject.VBComponents
                On Error Resume Next
                .Remove .Item("Module1")
                .Remove .Item("UserForm1")
                On Error GoTo ErrHandler
                .Import strTempModule
                .Import strTempUserForm
            End With
            .Close SaveChanges:=True
            lngCnt = lngCnt + 1
        End With
        strFile = Dir
    Loop

    Kill strTempModule
    Kill strTempUserForm

    MsgBox "Number of workbooks updated:  " & lngCnt, vbInformation

ExitTheSub:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & ":  " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error"
    Resume ExitTheSub

End Sub
```

Thanks Domenic Tamburino (MCC, MVP)!!!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way should be to use VBE's export and import functions.

1. In the VB Editor, select the module or form you want to export.
2. Right-click and select "Export file ...". This function is also available from the File menu in the ribbon.
3. Save the module as a file with the BAS extension. For the form the extension will be FRM.
4. Use the "Import file ..." function to import the BAS or FRM files into other documents.